# Onchange parameter to forward for the correct page

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

Hey I would like to use some quick change with the `onchange` parameter. Please can you help withe the `onchange` parameter to open a new page.

Well somebody will pick up for example `Basic info` and will be forwarded to the new page that is ready for this script with some columns.

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="script">
                    <select id="option" class="form-control input-sm" name="option" **onchange=""**>
                        <option>Ping</option>
                        <option>Traceroute</option>
                        <option>Basic info</option>
                        <option>Restart modules</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Are you looking for a `Post` kind of method? Or just a simple redirect? Not really clear what you want imho

Comment: thank you for your advice. The comment from jerome is working just fine. What im really interesting in is that I use POST method so what is picked up in optin im sending via POST method and work with that. If I use onchange="javascript:window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_self'); im sending the website via POST method and this i dont want. I still wanna send a name of the option. How can I make it? THX again for all the info

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying... DO or DON'T you want to use POST? Post as in posting a form and if you press F5 you get the message of resubmitting the values OR you want to use GET? Get as in passing the values as URL parameter...

Comment: well to explai to you my problem. I have wrote some python scripts where im using the the values of the option Ping, Traceroute and so on. The values are saved to file and Im accessing with python the values, so it is for me high imporant to send via post $POST (php) the correct value. If I use there the value as the web site I will not be able to save correct value to the file. and the scripts will not work properly. So my question is if there is a option to use code like

Comment: <option value="Ping">Ping</option>;<option value="Traceroute">Traceroute</option>, that could still use the code onchange="javascript:window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_self');" and redirect it to my different page regarding the option. Because for every script will be the page a little bit different, but still if I press submit I will send the value in option Ping, Traceroute and not a webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery for this. Create a [Post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for this

```js
    $(function(){
      $('#option').change(PostOption);
    });
    function PostOption(){
      $.post( "test.php", { option: $('#option').val() })
         .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data posted: " + data );
         })
         .error(function( error ) {
           console.log(error);
           alert("Something went wrong...");
         }
      );
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="option">
  <option>Select value</option>
  <option value=1>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the destination urls in the options, it should work (untested) with

```
onchange="javascript:window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_self');"
```

you will have to decide how you build the urls depending on the value of the options.